# What arrow is used to specify the relationship between a junction table and the FK tables

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, erd

This is part of my first database design. I am unsure what type of arrow to use to describe the relationship:

[image: A picture of the database and what relationship I need help with]

The tables are parking space, parking space features, and features.

**I am unsure of how to relate the parking space features to the parking space and the features.**

Bear in mind many features can be related to many parking space. that is why I created a junction table.

---

I have thought about it, and I think one parking space can be related to many different parking space features and not many to many as each parking space feature has the unique parking space id. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up logical and physical entities.

From the logical model point of view, you have two entities: "Parking Space" and "Feature". Each "Parking Space" can have one (or zero?) or more "Feature"s, and each "Feature" can apply to zero or more "Parking Space"s. Clearly, this is a many-to-many relationship.

When you move to the physical model, you represent this many-to-many relationship using the junction table, which becomes a kind of pseudo-entity "Parking Space Feature". Now each "Parking Space" has one/zero or more "Parking Space Feature"s, but each "Parking Space Feature" must only correspond to a single "Parking Space", so this becomes a one-to-many relationship. Similarly, each "Feature" can apply to zero or more "Parking Space Feature"s, but each "Parking Space Feature" must only correspond to a single "Feature" (again, one-to-many).

Now you can figure out how to represent these on the physical model diagram.